# Unable to change the BIOS password on HP machine using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, bios, passwords

I want to change bios password remotely for every HP PC in the network. However, I receive return code that is not listed in the documentation.

http://h20331.www2.hp.com/Hpsub/downloads/cmi_whitepaper.pdf

Here is my code that is ran remotely:

```
$Interface = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $targetComputer  -Namespace "root/hp/InstrumentedBIOS" -Class "HP_BIOSSettingInterface"
$Interface.SetBIOSSetting("Setup Password","<utf-16/>MyPassword","<utf-16/>")
```

The result of this command:

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     :
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        :
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         :
__NAMESPACE      :
__PATH           :
Return           : 32768
PSComputerName   :
```

As you can see the return code is 32768, however documentation lists only 1 to 6 codes. Of course nothing changed after reboot.

Do you know how to overcome this?

Comment: Is the last parameter that value because current password is not set? It looks out of place. Did you try omitting it or sending the same password there?

Comment: The linked white paper clearly indicates you can only query if a password has been set. I see no evidence that it should be possible to set the password remotely.

Comment: @Alex.... Here's a dump of a helper script when I had to do this for some HP workstations in the past. All Dell now which is a lot easier iirc but it's been a couple years at least since I had an HP to test this with. You may have some luck or get clarity from this code and the referenced [commented] link provided. Not sure if it's modified or a dump from there but I recall using it with success on some HP workstations remotely in the past: https://pastebin.com/iJ5vYVhg. Happy to post an answer and some additional and prettier detail if need and you tell me to.

Comment: You might need to `enter-pssession` and then run, or wrap in an `invoke-command` within `-scriptblock { }` may with `-credential (get-credential)` too. Got code in there that checks if password is set, to blank out the password, and to set a password. Firmware version may be of importance here too. Good luck! @Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys very much for responses!

This is my fault and inattention - I passed the password that did not meet the complexity in BIOS system. When I passed more complex password, it changed remotely.